# SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed

Tags: localhost, wampserver, roundcube

I have installed Roundcube webmail in my WAMPSERVER and I can access my emails via localhost/roundcube url, But I can not send email via my roundcube.
I get the alert with the following error.
**SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed**

I am sure there will be a solution.
please help me

Comment: Did you try these fixes https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=461

Comment: Or these https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=70821

Comment: Or these http://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=8561.0

Comment: Or any of the other 34,000 results to a google search "smtp error (-1) roundcube"

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for your reply and comments, But I tried all of them and could not succeeded, any way I solved it very simply.

Answer (score 1):

**I got the answer** 
I tried many ways but could not succeeded, Finally I opened my wamp/roundcubemail/config/defaults.inc.php and modified the following config value:
**$config['smtp_port'] = 465;**

it is useful for any one who has installed roundcube into WampSever in windows and can not send email.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the following:

**SMTP port**

default is `25`
use `587` for STARTTLS 
`465` for the deprecated SSL over SMTP

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried everything I could find, only to figure **I was editing the wrong configuration file** : the changes in `config/default.inc.php` didn't help because I had to edit `config/config.inc.php` instead.  It worked once I updated `$config['smtp_port']` to the right port (depends on your mail server configuration) in the right file.

FWIW, here is a procedure which might help debugging (it surely did for me, showing that my changes weren't taken into account) : in `program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_smtp.php`, replace the following line (line 134 in Roundcube 1.4.7)

```
$this->response[] = "Connection failed: " . $result->getMessage();
```

by

```
$this->response[] = "Connection failed: " . implode(", ", $CONFIG);
```

(check about 70 lines above to find the definition of the fields), then restart the Apache server, try to send an email and check `logs/errors.log`.

For the sake of SEO, here is the generic error that was shown in `logs/errors.log` :

> PHP Error: Invalid response code received from server (POST /roundcube/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1613339144872&_framed=1&_lang=en_US&_action=send)
> SMTP Error: Connection failed: Invalid response code received from server (POST /roundcube/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1613339144872&_framed=1&_lang=en_US&_action=send)

Furthermore, after this correction I couldn't connect back after logout, I had to configure `$config['default_port'] = 143` for IMAP.  For debugging one can use the same trick as above in file  `program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php`, line 200 (beware that  `$config` is lowcase in this file).

Answer (score -1):

just restart postfix, may work, i just do that.

```
> service postfix restart
```